# Windows Server Client Computer Backup Service will not start

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

I have a Windows Server 2012 Essentials box that will not start the "Windows Server Client Computer Backup Service". It is the only Service that is set to Automatic that will not start and I have no clue why!

When I try to start it I get the following: "The Windows Client Computer Backup Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some Services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

I have installed Windows Server 2012 Essentials Connector on several client PC's (installed via http://Server/Connect) and non of them can start backups because if this. I can't see anything in the Event Log that indicates any issues.

One other issue is that the Server itself is not listed in the Remote Web Access list of Computers however I can RDP to it using a normal RDP connection.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.channelpronetwork.com/blog/entry/windows-server-client-computer-backup-service-failed

Comment: Servers show up under "servers" and are visible to administrators only.

Comment: Yes I looked at http://www.channelpronetwork.com/blog/entry/windows-server-client-computer-backup-service-failed but I have no clue what she means. The link on that blog is also broken so I can't see what she is referring to.

Comment: I am the administrator yet I can only see the client PC in the Remote Web Access list. The Server is not showing up.

Comment: There is a folder where client backups are stored. Look for that folder and file. Sorry I have little experience with this and what I do have has been years ago now. I don't have a system in front of me to look at.

Comment: Thanks Appleoddity! This was the solution to get the Service and  BackUp Folder configured. Once I set the Client Back Up Folder Location the Service started. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0ee3e63c-68f7-43a8-880d-00f6c61f0208/client-backup-location?forum=winserveressentials

Comment: The only issue I have now is how to list the Server with all the Client PC's on the Remote Web Access web page.

Comment: Ok just off the wall... you know that the server is listed separately from the workstations right?

Comment: Yes, the server is listed on the dashboard but how do I get it listed on the Remote Web Access page?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help as it made me dig deeper and find the answers I needed to resolve these 2 issues.

1. Windows Server Client Computer Backup Service will not Start. ANSWER: Once I set the Client Back Up Folder Location in the Dashboard->Locations the Service started. [See here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0ee3e63c-68f7-43a8-880d-00f6c61f0208/client-backup-location?forum=winserveressentials)
2. Server is not listed in the list of Computers on the Remote Web Access Web Page. ANSWER: From the Dashboard, click 'Settings' in the title bar -> From Settings window, click 'Anywhere Access' in the left column -> in the Anywhere Access window, under 'Web site settings' click the 'customize...' button -> in the Customize window, select the 'Server connection options' tab -> select radio button for Dashboard or RDP connection.... found this here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d2fe84f-d817-497c-8323-acb399b51c31/remote-web-access-get-only-dashboard-from-server?forum=smallbusinessserver2011essentials